# Selenium Chrome Options crashes webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to use the Profile 3 from google chrome to open selenium webdriver but it crashes when I pass in the parameters in the Options class instance.

I followed all the steps listed here:
https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-use-a-specific-chrome-profile-in-python-selenium

Like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# browser configuration
opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# provide location where chrome stores the profiles
PROFILE_PATH = r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\My User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
opt.add_argument(PROFILE_PATH)
# provide profile name with which we want to open browser
opt.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 3')
# open the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)

def open_web_whatsap():    
    # open a website
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
    # wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(20)    

open_web_whatsap()
```

And it shows me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF628092142+3514994]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627CB0CE2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627B576AA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627B8B5AA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627B87F52]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627BD0AB4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627BC5D93]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627B94BDC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627B95C64]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6280BE16B+3695259]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF628116737+4057191]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF62810E4E3+4023827]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF627DE04F9+689705]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627CBC048]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627CB8044]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627CB81C9]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF627CA88C4]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFBEEBC7344+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFBEEEA26B1+33]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)

Comment: I found the cause of the problem, and it is a selenium bug because it crashes when you run the script with chrome opened. When I ran it without any browsers open it worked fine.